# Where can I get leather?

Tags: fallout-4

There seems to be a global shortage of leather. I can use it on almost all my armor, but I can't find any.

What items contain leather?

Is there another way to get bulk leather?

Comment: In my experience, it is the one item that "respawns" a lot. The skin from creatures, and the armor from raiders, can both be deconstructed into leather.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lots of armor and clothing items can scrap down to leather. Harnesses and Athletic Clothing in particular are very common and scrap to leather.

Alternately, you can go out hunting and kill mole rats, rad stags and other animals. Their skins should provide a bounty of leather for all of your crafting needs.

Comment: Harnesses? I've walked past 100 of those... Thanks

Comment: @Coomie Worth pointing out that you may need to drop items like the harness on the ground in a workshop, and then scrap them in workshop view. Leather armor is the first widely available source for most of my leather. It can be broken down at armor crafting stations.

Comment: @Coomie Armor is one of the best sources IMO, because there's so many raiders with junk leather armor (useless armor).  The downside is you get burdened quickly, but if you want junk, remember if you have a recipe/mod that requires leather and you remove all leather from your inventory and/or settlement inventory, you can use the tag for search option to put up a magnifying glass next to any items with leather (it removes the tag for any materials you have, and tags any you don't have).  Tagging items has been a big help for me.

Answer (score 3):

you can purchase "Shipment of Leather - 25" from Connie at Abernathy Farm(25% discount after minutemen quest), Greene at Graygarden(5% discount after minutemen quest), Lucas at Bunker Hill(has 2, void if you side with Cabot), Daniel at Finch Farm

[here is a link to all known shipments and who sells them](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3sx1ot/im_making_a_list_of_shipments_of_resources_that/)

Answer (score 2):

Scrap any of the following items for leather:

- Baseball
- Brahmin hide
- deathclaw hand
- molerat hide
- baseball glove
- teddy bear
- deathclaw hide
- radstag hide
- Yao guai hide

Or search around for the right merchant and you can buy a shipment of 25 leather... for a price.

Source: [Fallout 4 wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_crafting)

Answer (score 0):

The armor merchant in bunker hill sells shipments of leather, sometimes he even has more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Connie Abernathy in Abernathy Farms sells a single Shipment of Leather, and she's  persistent vendor.  After doing their initial quest, you get a significant discount from her as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can also get a shipment of leather from Abernathy farm.

Comment: The only reason i can see this being a bad answer is how vague it is.  It wouldn't hurt to mention for bulk leather they can buy a Shipment of Leather for 25 leather.  If you can give the NPC's name, a rough price, and keep the location (or any other locations you found), i think it would work. Just keep in mind if it's not a static NPC everyone will have, it won't count as a good answer.  And by Static NPC, i mean that no matter what happens, once you unlock the settlement, you will always get that same NPC.